# insert arguments in a vector's row in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix *100x100* that i converted it in a singular vector variable *10000x1* named `K` in *R*, created from a list as follows:

```
K_o <- unlist(Mist$K)
K <- as.double(format(round(K_o, 10), nsmall = 10) #keep the first ten decimals and read it as numeric
```

I want to store it in a `.txt` file that has the following arguments: first row: the lenght of a list `length(list)` which is 5 in my case, second row: `K 100 100` where, `K` is the name of the original matrix/vector,and  `100`, `100` are the `nrow(K)` and `ncol(K)` of the original matrix. The final `.txt` i want to look like this:

```
5
K 100 100
2.1840028592
6.3920476950
45.9584730261
3.7877586843
.
.
.
```

How do i manage to do that? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
K_o <- Mist$K
K <- as.double(format(round(K_o, 10), nsmall = 10))
writeLines(paste(length(list), '\nK', nrow(K_o), ncol(K_o), 
          '\n',paste0(K, collapse = "\n")), 'data.txt')
```